# Blog Images for Social Sites

Tags: wordpress, image, blogs, google-search

When I put images on my blog and they get included in social sites like Google plus it seems Google just grabs the first image it finds to include in posts.  However I want it to include a specific image on the page.  Is there a specific attribute to set for this on the image tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you set a "Featured Image" for your post. You don't even need to include it in the body of your post, just set the featured image via the "Add Media" button.

Then you can add the `og:image` meta property to the single post header to have other sites pick up this image automatically.

The easiest way to do this is to install an SEO plugin like [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/), which will automatically create the "og:image" property along with a few others targeted at other social networks.

Answer (score 0):

Social media usually consume Open Graph markup to understand your page.
For example you can tell them what's the featured image of you blog post, a short description that will not be truncated, etc.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yourblog.com/yourimage.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Your canonical URL" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your site name" />
```

I wrote a short guide for controlling the appearance of blog posts on social media.
For example do you know the new Twitter Cards?
[How to make your website look great on social media](http://www.idea-r.it/blog/116/en/how-to-make-website-look-great-on-social-media)